# Can a User-Defined Table Type (UDTT) parameter be mixed with other types

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-4.5, table-valued-parameters

I have a stored procedure that takes 3 parameters, 1st and 2nd parameters are of type varchar, last one is user defined table type.

When I EXEC the Stored Procedure through `ExecuteNonQuery`, it throws an exception:

> [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with ttOrderItems"}

The `ttOrderItems` is the User-Defined Table Type.

Is this behaviour normal? It does not take mix of parameters when one of the parameter is User-Defined Table Type?

Here are the code fragments that call the stored procedure:

```cs
public DataSet execProc(string storedProcedureName, IDictionary<string, object> prms = null)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, scon))
            {
                DataSet rs = new DataSet();
                if (prms != null) SetupParams(storedProcedureName, cmd, prms);
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    //using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) da.Fill(rs);
                    //{
                    //    da.Fill(rs);
                    //}
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                        return rs;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    scon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```cs
private void SetupParams(string RoutineName, SqlCommand cmd, IDictionary<string, object> prms, bool keepConnectionOpen = true)
        {
            if (cmd != null) cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            string pname = "";
            DataTable tblParams = Select("Select * from dbo.ftRoutineSchema('" + RoutineName + "')");
            foreach (DataRow dr in tblParams.Rows)
            {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter p = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter();
                pname = dr["COLUMnNAME"].ToString().ToLower();
                p.ParameterName = pname;
                pname = pname.Remove(0, 1).ToLower(); // remove @  sign
                if (prms.Keys.Contains(pname)) p.Value = prms[pname];
                string direction = dr["Direction"].ToString().ToLower();
                string sptype = (string)dr["DataType"];
                string[] sx = dr["DataType"].ToString().Split(new char[] { '(', ',', ')' });
                try
                {
                    #region case type switch
                    switch (sx[0].ToLower())
                    {
                        case "int":
                            p.DbType = DbType.Int32;//=int.Parse(sx[2]);
                            break;
                        case "bigint":
                            p.DbType = DbType.Int64;
                            break;
                        case "varchar":
                            p.DbType = DbType.String;
                            p.Size = int.Parse(sx[1]);
                            break;
                        case "nvarchar":
                            p.DbType = DbType.String;
                            p.Size = int.Parse(sx[1]);
                            break;
                        case "decimal":
                            p.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
                            break;
                        case "datetime":
                            p.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
                            break;
                        case "ntext":
                        case "text":
                            p.DbType = DbType.String;
                            p.Size = 65536;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    switch (direction)
                    {
                        case "in": p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; break;
                        case "out": p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; break;
                        case "rc": p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                    #endregion
                    if (sx[0] == "table type")
                    {
                        p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

When I exec the same proc through following T-SQL, it works as expected:

```sql
use edi
go
declare @items dbo.ttOrderItems
insert @items
            select 1,'574114-023',1,'EA',720,'2014-Oct-14',null,null
union all select 2,'574116-035',8,'EA',1865.5,'2014-Oct-10',null,null
exec dbo.prCatalogItems '010','000164',@items
```

---

```sql
CREATE function [dbo].[ftCatalogItems](@comno varchar(3),@cuno varchar(6),@items  ttOrderItems readonly) returns table as
    /*-------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @COMNO VARCHAR(3)='010',@CUNO VARCHAR(6)='000164'
    declare @items ttOrderItems;
    insert @items( position,ItemCode        ,QtyOrdered ,UOM    ,PriceQuoted,RequiredBy     ,ExpectedOnDock ,BackOrdered)
    select                              1,'1231-221'    ,1                  ,'EA'   ,20.20          ,'2014-11-01'   ,'2014-11-01'       ,0
    union  select                   2,'110223-245',10                   ,'EA'   ,2001.20        ,'2014-11-01'   ,'2014-11-01'       ,0


    select * from @items
    --------------------------------------------------------*/
    return(

    select 
                Position
                ,ItemCode
                ,QtyOrdered
                ,'EA' UOM
            ,PriceQuoted
            ,RequiredBy
            ,Isnull(c.Net,0.00) Net
            ,[Qty.] QtyApplicable
                ,Status=case 
                    when ItemCode is null then 'Not in Catalog' 
                    when [From] > getdate() then 'Availle only on or after '+Convert(varchar(30),[From],106)
                    when  datediff(DD,getdate(),isnull(nullif([To],''),'4712-01-01')) < 1 then 'EXPIRED'
                    when items.PriceQuoted != c.Net then 'Quoted Price does not match Catalog price'
                    else coalesce(c.[Item Code],'Invalid/non-existent Item')
                end 

from @items items
Left Join ediCatalog c on ltrim(c.[Item Code])=[ItemCode] AND COMNO=@COMNO AND c.[Customer Id.] =@CUNO  and c.[Server]=dbo.fsBaanServer()

)
```

---

```sql
ALTER proc [dbo].[prCatalogItems](@comno varchar(3),@cuno varchar(6),
                                  @items ttOrderItems readonly) as
Begin
    select * from dbo.ftCatalogItems(@comno,@cuno,@items)
end;
```

Comment: Can you post your `C#` code that calls the stored procedure and passes the parameters?

Comment: There is more information in the exception. Also, you haven't provided the T-SQL where the actual error is. This mass of code has nothing to do with the error. Closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `AddWithValue`, nor do you need to specify the UDTT name as you are calling a stored procedure (specifying `TypeName` is only required for parameterized ad hoc SQL).

What is the type of the object in your `prms` collection? You have three options of what to pass in as the `SqlParameter.Value` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx ):

1. DataTable
2. DbDataReader
3. method that returns IEnumerable

So, the main thing to do is:

1. Make sure you are passing in one of the above
2. Keep the line that does `p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;`
3. Don't use `.ToString()';
4. Get rid of the entire `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());` line as the value was set via `if (prms.Keys.Contains(pname)) p.Value = prms[pname];`.
5. Move `p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;` up to the `switch (sx[0].ToLower())` and get rid of the `if (sx[0] == "table type")` block through the `else`, but obviously keep the `cmd.Parameters.Add(p);`.

Comment: You nailed it, i was passing the third parameter.. (udtt) as a string ? , How stupid I am. Thanks

Comment: @TonyP , not stupid, sometimes it is just hard to see the needle in the haystack when you have been looking at it for a long time. Also, if it was not clear, you don't need the entire line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());` as the value was set towards the top already.

Comment: ,the only change needed was,   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value); instead of cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString()); Thanks again.

Comment: @TonyP : I understand that the one change alone worked. What I am saying is, there is some unnecessary code there. I have updated my answer with the optimizations. But there is really no need to "AddWithValue" when you have already set the value. Am just trying to help reduce complexity :). Either way, glad it works.